i want clear only work UniqueID = 2097153, but this macro clear all project data, what need fix it in it?
I'm trying to master VBA on ms project, and I found the code, I tried to adapt it for myself, but somehow it doesn't work out so far
Sub ClearActualHours()
Dim tsk As Task
Dim names As String
projStart = ActiveProject.ProjectStart
projEnd = ActiveProject.ProjectFinish
For Each tsk In ActiveProject.Tasks
        Dim asn As Assignment
        For Each asn In tsk.Assignments
            If asn.UniqueID = 2097153 Then
            Dim TSValues As TimeScaleValues
            Set TSValues = asn.TimeScaleData(projStart, projEnd, pjAssignmentTimescaledActualWork, pjTimescaleYears)
                Dim tsv As TimeScaleValue
            For Each tsv In TSValues
          tsv.Clear
         Next tsv
        asn.Work = 0
       End If
Next asn
  tsk.Work = 0
     Next tsk
End Sub

And it doesn't work

it doesn't work doesn't convey any information. How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

i want clear only work UniqueID = 2097153, but this macro clear all project data, what need fix it in it?
